# CALayer -hitTest: not respecting containsPoint: overload

Tags: iphone, ipad, calayer, hittest

Back again and have a different question with the same function that I posted before:

```
- (AIEnemyUnit *) hitTestForEnemyUnit:(CGPoint)where {
    CALayer * layer = [self hitTest:where];

    while (layer) {
        if ([layer isKindOfClass:[AIEnemyUnit class]]) {
            return (AIEnemyUnit *)layer;
        } else {
            layer = layer.superlayer;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

I have a bomb that the user drags on top of the enemy so that it is displayed directly above the AIEnemyUnit.  For this bomb I implemented the CALayer `-containsPoint:` to return NO during a drag to allow -hitTest: to pass through the layer.  Basically this type of hit testing was working fine with these "pass-through" layers as long as I only used CGImageRef contexts.  However once I started implementing sublayers for additional effects on the bomb,  `-hitTest:` immediately broke.  It was obvious, the new layers were capturing the `-hitTest:`.  I tried implementing the same technique by overloading `-containsPoint:` for these layers, but it was still returning the bomb's generic CALayer subclass instead of passing through.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the "where" point is not relative to your "self" layer. You need to convert these points between the layers coordinate systems using:

– convertPoint:fromLayer: or 
– convertPoint:toLayer:

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/convertPoint:fromLayer:

Comment: No, the exact code was working fine without the additional layers and some of the elements are quite small so I know that "where" was functioning properly.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by putting everything on a second "root" layer (called "gameLayer") the same size as the original.  Then during the UIPanGestureRecognizer, I move the bomb element from "gameLayer" into my UIView.layer.  Then while I am testing for a AIEnemyUnit, I only run the hitTest on the "gameLayer".

```
- UIView.layer --------- gameLayer 
           |                |
     dragObj(bomb)     gameElements
                            |
                           bomb
```